# delete second occurence of a node in single linklist

Tags: c, linked-list

this is an interview question and I was trying to solve it.
I completely solved and I realized that I missed one test case.

The question is , how would you delete a second occurrence of a node in a linklist.
FOr example:
1->2->9->5->2 and I enter 2.
so the out put should be 1->9>5->2

I did solve using two pointers first and second which will keep on swaping based on the findings.
And I am always storing the previous pointer. for example in above example I am storing at 1 and 5. so that I could always delete the next one.

But what if the linklist becomes like this:
2->7->9->2
and the out out has to be 7->9->2.

Do let me know, if you guys have any questions?

Comment: The question is not clear. Is this a single-linked list or a double-linked? You will not have or use any prev pointer in a single-linked one, yet your ASCII lists look like they are single-linked...?

Comment: If you delete second occurance of `2` in `2->7->9->2`, the output should be `2->7->9` not `7->9->2`.

Comment: @Ludin: it's a singlelinklist

Comment: @Als And what is the second occurance if that list is double-linked? The question needs clarification.

Comment: @Als: I know we can perceive this question like that. The it is easy to delete the second occurence.but waht if the interviwer says like myway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Iterate the list left to right, assuming single-linked list.
- If the next node is the one you are looking for, point at it with a temp pointer.
- Let the current node's next pointer point at next->next.
- Delete the node the temp pointer points at.

Comment: The question is, what if the head itself is 2nd occurence like in my example.

Comment: How can the head be the 2nd occurance of anything? That doesn't make any sense. I assume you mean, what if the head itself is the node I'm looking for. Then start the iteration outside the list. You'll have a pointer you use as iterator. Linked lists tend to threat the head and tail as special cases by their nature. There are countless source codes examples of this all over the net.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the simplest way to avoid duplicates in a simply linked list is to have it ordered. This way you will detect the duplicate when inserting the element.

Don't know if this is an acceptable solution for your interview question as it does not "delete occurrences".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a single linked list used as a queue, where the start pointer is pointing to the last element in the queue, and that we can have more than 2 occurrences of the same element, then I suggest the following algorithm:

```
int removeSecondOccurrence( List_t **start, int target )
{
  if( start == NULL || *start == NULL )
    return -10;

  List_t *current= *start,
        **first  = NULL,
        **second = NULL;

  if( ( *start )->data == target )
    first= start;

  while( current->next != NULL )
  {
    if( current->next->data == target )
    {
      if( first != NULL )
        second= first;
      first=  &current->next;
    }
    current= current->next;
  }
  if( second != NULL )
  {
    List_t *tmp= ( *second )->next;

    free( *second );
    ( *second )= tmp;

    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WE can use Hashing heree,We traverse the link list from head to end. For every newly encountered element, we check whether it is in the hash table: if yes, we remove it; otherwise we put it in the hash table
Time compexity will be:O(n)